# sequence already created but error showing RA-02289: sequence does not exist

Tags: sql, oracle, t-sql, oracle10g, sequence-sql

I created a sequence in ORACLE 10g database

```
CREATE SEQUENCE "test_seq" 
START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 3 
NOMAXVALUE NOMINVALUE NOORDER NOCYCLE NOCACHE;
```

I also have a table in database to use this sequence

```
CREATE TABLE USER_TEST
(
   U_NAME   VARCHAR2 (100),
   PWD      VARCHAR2 (100),
   SR_NO    NUMBER
)
NOCACHE
LOGGING;
```

But when inserting values in table using

```
INSERT INTO USER_TEST VALUES( test_seq.NEXTVAL,'QWERTY','1QWE')
```

it gives following error

> ORA-02289: sequence does not exist

What should I do to use my sequence inserting data to my table.If i'm not using sequence insert command works perfectly.

Comment: You created a sequence with a case-sensitive identifier `"test_seq"`.  You then try to use a non-quoted identifier `test_req`-- that won't work.  Your non-quoted identifier is also misspelled.  If your `create sequence` statement is accurate, `values( "test_seq".nextval, ...` would work.  But more likely you want to use case-insensitive identifiers for your sequences (and your other objects).  And I'm not sure whether some of the issues are due to typos in the question you're posting.

Comment: If i use 

`insert into USER_TEST values( "test_seq".NEXTVAL,'anand','ansrargu')`

it is showing 

`ORA-01722: invalid number`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using wrong seq name `test_req` while correct name is `test_seq`

```
INSERT INTO USER_TEST VALUES('QWERTY','1QWE',"test_seq".NEXTVAL)
```

Second mistake is your insert statement is wrong, as your column name is not specified and your auto-generate field is on last in column list so you have to specify `test_seq.NEXTVAL` in last in insert statement

[SEE Working Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/15d928/1)